# How to convert [some nested input object] to [Generic 1] to [Generic 2] without losing compile-time type-safety?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

Imagine that I have some arbitrary input object like this:

```
interface InputType {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    location: {
        x: number;
        y: number;
    }
}
```

Imagine I then convert it into the following generic type (Generic #1):

```
// Same structure as T, replacing strings and numbers with a function that receives that type as an arg
type Generic1<T> =
    T extends string ? (val: string) => void :
    T extends number ? (val: number) => void :
    {
        [k in keyof T]: Generic1<T[k]>
    }
```

This second structure is compile-time safe, such that if `T = InputType` I will have compile-time knowledge of all the properties of `InputType` in `Generic1`.

```
const output = convertInputToGeneric1(inputType);
output.name("i am a string"); // works!
```

---

Imagine I want a 2nd generic, exactly like the first except for 1 small difference.

Instead of converting `input` to `Generic 2`, I want to convert `Generic 1` to `Generic 2` (which as we established already, has the same structure as `input`). Again, it must be compile-time type-safe.

How can I do this?

---

Here is a TS Playground link of what I currently have: https://tsplay.dev/wRp8xm

Comment: coulf you please provide minimum reproducable example?

Comment: See playground link please

Comment: I meant `minimum`

Comment: Unfortunately that is the minimum needed to reproduce the problem. What's required is (1) An arbitrary object (in my case I have `InputType`); (2) A generic that maps the structure of `input` (to prove that type-safety works - in my example this is `Generic1`) (3) A generic that maps the structure of `input` but requires access to `Generic1` to build its data (in my case this is `Generic2`). If you look at the bottom of the playground code, you'll see 1 generic output being type-safe, and another that isn't. I'd like to make the 2nd one type-safe also. Sorry if the code is long!

Comment: Here is the code working, by not trying to constrain `Generic2` to `T` https://tsplay.dev/Woq0PN